# SSIS SQL Agent job - Error: for each sub folder : The get enumerator method of the for each enumerator

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Package , which runs fine in Visual studio. The package uses a for each file loop and the variable points to a folder like this:

```
\\server\d$\foldername\subfolder\
```

When I deploy the package on SSMS, when I execute the package I get the following error:

Error 1: FLC - for each sub folder: Error: The GetEnumerator method of the ForEach enumerator has failed with error 0x80131509 "null" . This occurs when the for each enumerator cannot enumerate

Error 2: FLC - For each sub folder: Error The object in the variable "User: ProductFolderList" does not contain an enumerator.

Below is the code used:

```
string folder = Dts.Variables["User::varProcessingFolderLocation"].Value.ToString(); 
Dts.Variables["User::ProductFolderList"].Value = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder);   
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

SSMS version is 2017, visual studio solution is built in 2016 and project configuration is VNext. I have verified the permissions of the folder and the ID with which I am running it has full control.
How to fix this? Thanks

[Code with Message box]

```
string folder = Dts.Variables["User::varProcessingFolderLocation"].Value.ToString(); 

MessageBox.Show(folder); 

 Dts.Variables["User::ProductFolderList"].Value = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folder); 

 MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::ProductFolderList"].Value.ToString())
```

Comment: This typically means that you have an invalid path from the SQL Server, or that the Agent account running the package doesn't have the right permissions.  I've never heard of any other explanation for this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added message box to check the issue. In the first message box, I am getting as  \\server\foldername\subfolder\

In the second message box, I am getting as System.String[] - This is the issue
I have updated the code in the first thread with the message box.